# How to refresh only a div with ajax every 15 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want that this div refresh every 15 seconds, it already refresh, the thing is that it refresh once, the next time that refresh the table its removed and i dont know why :(

```
    <div class="refresh">   
    <table class="editinplace">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellidos</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is the ajax where append the json

```
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function ()
        {
        $('.refresh').load('index.html');
        }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds


   $(document).ready(function() 
{ 

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "editinplace.php?tabla=1"
    })
    //Vector
    .done(function(json)  
    {
        json = $.parseJSON(json)
        for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++)
        {   
            $('.editinplace').append
            (
                "<tr><td class='id'>"
                +json[i].id
                +"</td><td>"
                +json[i].nombre
                +"</td><td>"
                +json[i].apellidos
                +"</td><td>"
                +json[i].telefono
                +"</span></td><td class='editable' data-campo='status'><span>"
                +json[i].status
                +"</span></td></tr>");
        }

    });
```

Comment: and the code you have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){

$('div').ajax({

url: "test.php",

}).done(function() {

$(this).html( "done" );

});

}, 15000); // 15000 micro second = 15 sec.

});
```

URL will be the name of the php file. You can also specify the name of the DIV

Answer (score 0):

Here `refresh_div()` function call at every `15 seconds`.

```
function refresh_div()
{
   // Your ajax code here
}
setInterval('refresh_div()', 15000);
```